# Rendering part of large Visual object performance

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that generate graphs from some input files. The user has the option to generate an image from these graphs. The graph is created using an external library that draws into a custom visual object (inherits from Canvas).

## The Functionality

I created a custom functionality to create the image out of this canvas and it has worked well so far. The problem I'm having is related to its performance when the need to generate an image out of VERY large graph.

The images generated by this functionality has always been big, to be able to generate these large images I generate smaller "chunks" (configurable, but currently at 2000x2000px, larger chunks can lose quality and smaller is slower). After these "chunks" are created I merge them using another external library (this last works fine and it is really fast, the issue does not lie here).

## The Issue

The problem is happening that the larger the original visual is, each chunk rendering takes longer.

The problem is that the larger the image is, each "chunk" rendering takes longer. I'll post the code here later, but I've noticed that the "RenderTargetBitmap.Render()" method when using my "DrawingVisual" (with the chunk information). As an example, this method call takes 400ms+ on my local tests where the Canvas is **74052.75px x 1119.4px**; the total image creation time takes about 20 secs.

This would not be that bad, but there was a requirement where a large (MUCH larger) image has to be created and **each chunk** is taking 5 minutes to generate, so my estimation is that it would take about **60 days**.

## The Code

This is the code I'm using at each "chunk" loop. The code is modified to remove some cancellation token and progress report calls. I also added a comment to highlight the call that takes 400+ms.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
    {
        int row = i, col = j; //this is done because task start could have a modified value on call
        Rect rect = new Rect(
            col * maxWidth,
            row * maxHeight,
            col + 1 < colCount ? maxWidth :
                surfaceWidth - (colCount - 1) * maxWidth,
            row + 1 < rowCount ? maxHeight :
                surfaceHeight - (rowCount - 1) * maxHeight);

        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush brush = new VisualBrush(element)
            {
                Viewbox = rect,
                ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
                Stretch = Stretch.None
            };
            dc.DrawRectangle(brush,
                null,
                new Rect(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height));
        }

        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(

            (int)(rect.Width * (imgdpi / DEFAULT_DPI)),
            (int)(rect.Height * (imgdpi / DEFAULT_DPI)),
            imgdpi,
            imgdpi,
            PixelFormat);

        //***********************//
        //THIS IS THE CALL THAT TAKES 400+ms
        //***********************//
        bitmap.Render(visual);


        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        encoder.Save(ms);

        //... Some additional code to work with the chunk asynchronously
    }
}
```

## Things I've tried

I've tried several things:

1. Calling Dispatcher.DisableProcessing: I was thinking that it could have been that the UI kept trying to update the surface while processing the chunks (althought my understanding that if it has not been modified it shouldn't be much of a problem). But this did not change the processing time.
2. While creating the VisualBrush object to assign to it smaller Viewports (chunk size or bigger). The time actually increased.
3. Adding CacheMode to the Canvas: The time actually increased and the image looked low resolution.
4. Some additional desperate measures that made no sense haha.

## Additional Information

Since I'm not completely sure how this Render functionality works internally (And I have searched for information on these, but what I've found is superficial at best) I'm not sure if the cause is the large surface or the number of controls in the surface (or a combination of both). So here is some additional information on the test case that is taking 400ms per render:

- Surface Size is: **74052.75px x 1119.4px**.
- N. of Graph's Nodes: **1977**.
- N. of Connectors (Arrows): **2052**.
- Each Control visual is defined in the XAML using resources.
- Each Graph Node is a Filled Rectangle with a Textblock at its center.
- Each Connector is a straight line with a triangle at one of its edges.

Also, since the very large image generation is not something that will happen that often, and not to a regular user. I would not mind if the solution provided sacrifices UI responsiveness.

## Notes added to clarify some concerns in the comments section

- The graph is shown on screen to the user, this can be manipulated by it.
- The "Store as Image" functionality is just an additional optional functionality to save the graph as an Image file. (This works under normal load, the speed issue happens with an unnusually large graph).

I'd appreciate any help you could provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried multithreading? Also, if you're working with image processing and performance is critical, maybe it's time to reconsider whether WPF is really what you should be using.

Comment: There is also a solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736287/capturing-a-window-with-wpf) where instead of re-rendering the visuals, you use Win32 commands to capture those pixels on the screen. The problem with that approach, of course, is that the entire image you are trying to capture needs to be visible on the screen, which seems unlikely given the image resolutions you say you are working with.

Comment: @Abion47 I have tried Multithreading, the problem is that the DrawingVisual, brush, RenderTargetBitmap and Bitmap Encoder needs to work at the Dispatcher's thread. I'm actually using multithreading after this part is done to work in parallel what I can. And I have to stick with WPF because of the library I'm using.

Comment: @Abion47 About the other solution, I'll give it a go, scrolling through the surface might be possible, I'll have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @Abion47 You do realise WPF is hardware-accelerated when used properly?  You can write your own shaders too

Comment: @MickyD I'm aware. But just because you can doesn't mean you should, and there are reasons that shaders in WPF applications never really caught on. What OP is essentially trying to do is attach a bunch of controls to a (presumably) hidden window then capture the render of that window as an image, all to generate an image of a graph. Not even hardware-acceleration changes the fact that this is overkill at its finest.

Comment: @Abion47 _"...doesn't mean you should..."_ - what a silly thing to say.  [Shaders never caught on?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects?view=netframework-4.7.2). OK.  _"...OP is essentially trying to do is attach a bunch of `controls` to a (presumably) `hidden` window..."_ - a `DrawingVisual` is **not** a control.

Comment: I can see a few problems performance-wise.  I see you are creating a `RenderTargetBitmap` each time prior to the call to `Render()`.  I suggest you create it **once** and merely call `Clear()`.  Otherwise you are probably reaking havoc on `memory`.  You are **not** disposing the `MemoryStream`

Comment: @Abion47 The window is not hidden. The user can play around with the graph in real time, this is an additional functionality to export it as an Image. Of course, in the case of the HUGE graph that needs to be created this time the UI is not as responsive as it should, but again, this is not a regular ocurrence.

Comment: @MickyD MemoryStream is being disposed, it is just done in another thread that is why I'm not using Dispose, and it is done later. Some work is done in parallel after the image is created. The RenderTargetBitmap could be worked, it is something I though about handling, but the current issue happens since the first loop. So it is not the origin of the performance issue.

Comment: @MickyD I'm being simplistic for the sake of the character limit, but if you wanted to be pedantic, yes, my description of what he is doing is not _technically_ true. Instead, he's taking his existing controls, adding them to a `VisualBrush`, using that to paint a `DrawingVisual`, then rendering that to a `RenderTargetBitmap`. And how is getting that specific helpful in describing OP's general workflow?

Comment: @MickyD And no, the use of shaders never really caught on in WPF. but apparently you don't know what "never caught on" means. The capability of using shaders to add custom effects has been supported in WPF for ages, which only makes sense as WPF uses DirectX as its graphics engine. That being said, outside of specially made libraries, it has always been recommended (and usually followed) to use existing effects and compositing to gain a particular result whenever possible. Shaders are cool, but are also error-prone and difficult to debug, hence the recommendation.

Comment: @MickyD So yes, just because you _can_ do something doesn't always mean that you should. Shaders are a neat trick, but 999 times out of 1000 they are overkill for the task at hand and you can achieve the same look just using WPF's various compositing capabilities. If you're just trying to experiment or show off, then more power to you, but if you find yourself using shaders in a production-level WPF application, either you have a damn good reason for needing them or you need to step back and reassess your priorities.